# Hibernate: how can I get data of foreign keys optional?

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate

I have a table containing customer data, which is connected with a foreign key to an order table. Obviously one customer can have more than one order, but every order has exactly one customer.

When I retrieve the customer data, Hibernate automatically gets the connected orders of the client. But in many cases I just need the customer data. Out of performance reasons I would like to avoid that, and only get the orders when I need them.

Is it possible to do that? And does this actually influence the performance?

Thanks!
noise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've mapped the associations between `customer` and `order` with the `Fetchtype.LAZY` when you load the customer the orders would be loaded only when you access them. In this way the loading would be faster.

Contrary the `FetchType.EAGER` will load the collection of `orders` when you load the `customer` object, impacting on the performances.

You can tell `Hibernate` what kind of association fetching you prefer, an example using annotations is:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Comment: Is it also possible to decide the fetch type dynamically for every Hibernate-DB-call?

Comment: This should be another question. Anyway you can in a `criteria` query using the `setFetchMode()`.